# How to output 3d geometries via grass plugins v.drape, v.to.3d in qgis?

Tags: qgis, 3d, qgis-grass-plugin

When I try to process either a 2d Linestring or a 3d MultilinestringZ vector through the v.drape or v.to.3d processing tools in qgis, I get an error stating that it is outputting a 2d geometry instead of 3d and should set a lco flag to force 3d geometry:

```
WARNING: Vector map <output660b8ef0560648d183efaf4701ffc6ea> is 3D. Use format specific layer creation options (parameter 'lco') to export <in 3D rather than 2D (default).
```

This checks out because the file (that is created successfully) reports **Geometry: Line(Linestring)** in the layer properties

So, what flag is needed to force a 3d geometry with v.drape? I looked at the v.drape [docs](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/v.drape.html) but could not determine what the lco flag should be.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving the default output (temporary/memory .gpkg) for the grass processing tools was the problem. If you output to a real shapefile, v.to.3d and v.drape function normally and output MultiLinestringZ geometries without any special lco flags.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not using Grass but Here's an example with ogr2ogr if yoiu want another solution...

ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -nlt POLYGON,25D -lco encoding=1251 output.shp input.shp -overwrite