# Adding Z (DEM) to my X and Y table (CSV) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, dem

I have CSV with Name (ID), X and Y. Also have DEM. Hoping to combine my CSV that has Name with corresponding X and Y, then add the Z from DEM.

"Join Attributes from Location" and "Point Sampling" tool do not seem to do what I need.

Answer (score 1):

v.drape and v.to.3d in the Processing Toolbox support point features. So, load your .csv x,y data into the map, copy all the features and paste them as a temporary scratch layer (so you can have processing tools to interact with the points) and then make sure the units on your DEM are what you want to get attached to the points. Then run one of those two processing tools. The output should be a new memory layer with the Z values attached.

Related posts:

[how-to-output-3d-geometries-via-grass-plugins-v-drape-v-to-3d-in-qgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/388171/how-to-output-3d-geometries-via-grass-plugins-v-drape-v-to-3d-in-qgis)

[how-to-calculate-the-3d-length-of-line-segment-in-qgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/156519/how-to-calculate-the-3d-length-of-line-segment-in-qgis)